# How to select the first li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you select the first li, if it does not have an unique identifier?

In the below list, (output via a cms) the only identifier is not unique and applies to all li elements. I would like to select an li, based on the content of the li. If the content of the li matches the string then I want to add a new li to the top.

String is "Audi", if the li contains "Audi" then add a new li to before the first instance.

**Updated** 
JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xbmz1umk/5/

```
    <div class = "carContainer">
    <li class="carPart">
    <p class="car_title"><a href="car1.php" class="car_link">Audi Red</a>
    </p>
    </li>
    <li class="carPart">
    <p class="car_title"><a href="car2.php" class="car_link">Audi Blue</a>
    </p>
    </li>
    <li class="carPart">
    <p class="car_title"><a href="car3.php" class="car_link">Audi Black</a>
    </p>
    </li>
    <li class="carPart">
    <p class="car_title"><a href="car4.php" class="car_link">BMW Red</a>
    </p>
    </li>
    <li class="carPart">
    <p class="car_title"><a href="car5.php" class="car_link">BMW Blue</a>
    </p>
    </li>
    <li class="carPart">
    <p class="car_title"><a href="car6.php" class="car_link">BMW Black</a>
    </p>
    </li>
    <li class="carPart">
    <p class="car_title"><a href="car4.php" class="car_link">Fiat Red</a>
    </p>
    </li>
    <li class="carPart">
       <p class="car_title"><a href=“car5.php” class="car_link">Fiat Blue</a>
    </p>
    </li>
     <li class="carPart">
    <p class="car_title"><a href="car6.php" class="car_link">Fiat Black</a>
    </p>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: your question is very unclear to me. _"look for the first time car_title called Audi is mentioned"_ - who or what mentions `car_title` in which way? where is your `javascript` / `jQuery` code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Apologies, i've created a fiddle to explain in a little more detail

http://jsfiddle.net/xbmz1umk/3/

My current JS will add to every li with the class carPart, I would like to only added it before the first li that contains the html Audi

Comment: `<div = “carContainer”>`?? really???

Comment: Not too sure what's happened there @TJ the fiddle has the correct markup

Comment: Please update the question with the correct code and link to fiddle...

Comment: FYI, You have specified multiple `class` attributes on the same elements, the later will be simply ignored... can you can specify multiple classes in a single `class` attribute by separating them with space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the first `<li>` containing `Audi` using [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector.

```
 $("li:contains('Audi'):first")
```

You can insert a new list item [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) this using

```
$("li:contains('Audi'):first").before("<li></li>");
```